# In Microsoft Test Manager, is there a way to assign multiple roles to a single machine in an environment?

Tags: tfs, test-environments, lab-management

We're currently setting up Lab managed environments using TFS 2012 Lab Management at my company. In the Microsoft Test Manager, you need to define environments in which tests can be run. In each environment, you must have one or more machines specified to run tests. Each machine can be assigned a role within the environment. Is there any way to assign multiple roles to a single machine within an environment ? e.g. I'd like to be able to define multiple UI test runs, but have a single machine perform multiple roles within our application ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently possible to assign multiple roles to the same machine. Most folks create another role that means two together.